# Have multiple conditions in subset dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to filter a dataframe with subset function, I have many labels that are being attached and I only want a specific 15 labels.

## DataFrame (Example):

```
X1     | X2    | Value
GCF2423 GCF1393   0
GCF2423 GCF1520   0
GCF2423 GCF3487   1
GCF1393 GCF2423   0
GCF1393 GCF1520   1
GCF1520 GCF1393   0
GCF1520 GCF3517   1
GCF3487 GCF1520   0
```

## Code Snippet 1

```
p <- ggplot(data = dfids, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(value, 
                                                                     levels = c(-1, 0, 1))), colour = "white")

p <- p + geom_label_repel(data = dfids), aes(label = X1), size=2.5,nudge_x=-2,nudge_y=-2)
```

Which Produced Figure:

[image]

As mentioned I want to do various conditions, for which I was using method of subset on my dataframe as below, when I try to do more than one condition, it only uses the first two conditions available. I'm not sure if I would have to modify instead the *aes()* function and not the *subset()* function.

## Code Snippet 2

```
p <- p + geom_label_repel(data = subset(dfids, X1 == "GCF2423" | X1 == "GCF1520" | X1 == "GCF1393"), 
                            aes(label = X1), size=2.5,nudge_x=-2,nudge_y=-2)
```

Which Produces Figure:

[image]

Comment: I was able to correct this issue by using the _filter()_ function from the _dplyr_ r package (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this issue by using the *filter()* function from the *dplyr* r package, I have shared this comment on my own question in case someone runs into a similar issue:

```
p <- p + geom_label_repel(data = filter(dfids, X1 == "GCF2423" | X1 == "GCF1393" | X1 == "GCF1520"), 
                              aes(label = X1), size=2.5,nudge_x=-2,nudge_y=-2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your situation, but I was able to just use the subset function without problems.

Did you test the subset function outside of the ggplot, and did it have the same results there?

Comment: Yes, the subset function works fine but in the case when I'm using with ggplot, it does not really work..